# In between loop iteration syntax

Tags: loops

In most languages, if you want to perform an action only *between* loop iterations you have to write something like the following:

```
for item in items:
    *DO SOMETHING HERE*
    if item is last in list:
         DON'T DO/UNDO THE IN-BETWEEN ACTION
```

That last if statement if quite messy and not always obvious how to achieve, especially in for-each loops.

I'm wondering if there's a syntax in a particular language that allows you to execute statements *only if execution is **in between** loop iterations*.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What is the problem with : 
`for item in items:
    *DO SOMETHING HERE* ;
DON'T DO/UNDO THE IN-BETWEEN ACTION` ?

Comment: Then the action is done _after_ the last item, too, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running the "in-between task" at the end of the loop, you could do it at the beginning.

It becomes easier since you only have to check if the iteration is the first or not, which you can easily achieve with a boolean flag or an integer, like in the example below.

```js
let i = 0;
for (let x of [1,2,3,4]) {
  if (i++ > 0) {
    console.log('*');
  }
  console.log(x);
}
```